# Is there an improved canonical polyadic decomposition for symmetric tensors?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, exploratory-data-analysis, tensor

Let us suppose I want to find a [CP decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition) of a $n$-mode [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) $\mathcal{A}$. Fortunately the tensor has the permutation symmetry

$$\mathcal{A}[i_1, \cdots, i_n] = \mathcal{A}[\sigma (i_1), \cdots, \sigma (i_n)]$$

for all permutations $\sigma$ on the index set. I have read this to be either a *symmetric tensor* or a *supersymmetric tensor* depending on the author.

One of the limitations I have discovered about CP decomposition is that it requires a lot of memory. But clearly a symmetric tensor has a ton of redundant information.

Is there an improved canonical polyadic decomposition that leverages the fact that symmetric tensors have a lot of repeated entries?